# Need Multi-Line JS Strings

Tags: javascript

I have searched a lot on how to do this, but none of the solutions have been successful in my case.

I have built a very simple JS form which will generate text ready to copy and paste straight into an email.

My only problem now is getting that text appear exactly as I want it in the email (i.e. multi line).

Does anyone have any suggestions based on my code below?

**Not duplicate. I have already read/tried the examples in the other post and none of them work. Hence why I am creating a new question specifically for my code.**

```
function myFunction3() {
    var b, text;

    b = document.getElementById("type").value;

    if (b === "rfi") {
        text = "This is an RFI email";
    } else {
        text = "This is a bank details request email";
    }
    document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = text;
}
```

The HTML part is below:

```
<p id="demo3"></p>
```

Comment: Where is the multi line string you are talking about ?

Comment: Have you tried using a textarea instead of a textbox?

Comment: Hi, it's just the text in the if/else statements. I didn't actually include the full email I want. I should have.

Comment: The *question* is still a duplicate whether or not it worked for *you*. If you are having problems getting the answer from the other question to work, you should link to the other answer as a reference and demonstrate that you have tried it in your question with code. Then this question won't be considered a duplicate because you are asking a question about the other answer. Make sure you provide enough context here so the question stands on its own if the other one gets changed or deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var a = "First line.";
var b = "Second line.";
console.log(a + "\n" + b);
```

```js
var a = "First line.";
var b = "Second line.";
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = a + "<br/>" + b;
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: This should work, but in my site it doesn't.

Comment: @Chris for `innerHTML` you need `"<br/>"` instead of `"\n"`.

Comment: Ah yes! That works. Thanks Igor.